# changes from localhost wordpress to live site wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, localhost

For two months now I have been making changes to a local copy of a live wordpress website.

All of the changes were made in the custom theme directory in files such as **custom-template-page-functions.php** and **style.css** on my localhost version.

While i was working on the site on localhost the live site got more articles and content.

Now I am wondering what would be the most affective way to add these changes to the live site.

Comment: Have you made any changes in database, like adding plugins and editing theme through admin panel?

Comment: I only added **relative-url** plugin because I have been testing the localhost site on my phone thro ngrok tunnel, but i will delete it when done testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling (theme) and content should be agnostic of each other, so there shouldn't be the need to reflect a change in content within the localhost as it should just work.

Having said that, if you want to test that the content doesn't break anything, use Wordpress' in built exporter for the posts and then import it locally and you can test it with the new content. You may end up with duplication if you don't clear off the old content on localhost first, but it will allow you to check that nothing displays incorrectly.

Comment: So if I import the posts to localhost and hopefully nothng brakes i can just replace the files on ftp with those i made changes to ?

Comment: Theoretically, yes.

Comment: So I replaced my "modified" files with the originals from my backup, exported and imported content to my localhost and then replaced the original files with the modified ones and the changes worked once i cleared my browser cache and nothing broke and i didnt get no errors so I hope it dosent mess up the live site.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these changes you can try [Duplicator Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) for duplicate all the wordpress site.